# $\sigma$-algebra generated by subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by the intervals $(-1,0), (1,2)$ and $(4,6)$.

I am looking for -

1. The number of sets in $A$.
2. A function on $\mathbb{R}$ that is not measurable with respect to $A$.

**1.**

Well for each of the sets in $A$, we have that their complement must be in A so that means $(-1,0)^c, (1,2)^c$ and $(4,6)^c$ are in $A$.

The empty set must be in $A$.

All countable unions of $(-1,0), (1,2), (4,6), (-1,0)^c, (1,2)^c, (4,6)^c$ will be in $A$, although some of these unions will equal $\mathbb{R}$ so we don't want to count them multiple times.

**Is there a better, more formulaic, way of determining the number of sets in a $\sigma$-alegbra generated by a number of subsets (3 in this case)?**

**2.**

Consider the function $f(x) = x$

Now, for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ we must have that the set $S = \{x \mid f(x) > \lambda\}$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra $A$.

Well if we consider $\lambda = 0$ we have that $S = (0, \infty)$ and this set is not in $A$.

**So $f(x) = x $ is a function that is not measurable with respect to $A$?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because we have only finitely many generating sets, finitary operations suffice and the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets is simply the *algebra* generated by the sets under the operations of finite unions, finite intersections, and complementation.

Your three sets (call them $S_1$, $S_2$, and $S_3$) are pairwise disjoint and their union is not all of $\mathbb{R}$, so if we define $S_4 = \mathbb{R} \setminus (S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3)$ then we have a partition $\{S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4\}$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

The algebra generated by $\{S_1,S_2,S_3\}$ contains $S_4$, so it is the same as the algebra generated by $\{S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4\}$.  However, thinking of the algebra as being generated by a partition will help us count the number of sets it contains.

In general, an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on a set generated by an $n$-element partition $\{S_1,\ldots,S_n\}$ of that set will have $2^n$ elements. This is because mapping a subset (*e.g.* $\{S_1,S_3,S_4\}$) of the generating set to the union of that subset (*e.g.* $S_1 \cup S_3 \cup S_4$) gives a bijection $\mathcal{P}(S_1,\ldots,S_n) \to \mathcal{A}$.

Therefore in your case the number of sets generated is $2^4$.

For (2) your answer is correct assuming that the question is asking about measurable functions $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A}) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ where $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  It seems likely to me that the question is instead asking about measurable functions $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A}) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A})$, in which case the identity function *would* be measurable.  (Note the abuse of terminology here; the actual *functions* are the same in both interpretations, but measurability depends on which $\sigma$-algebras we put on the domain and co-domain.)

Comment: Excellent explanation thanks.

Comment: Regarding question 2, the algebra I am referring to is the algebra from question 1 which has $2^4$ elements as you explained. But if we have $f(x) = x$ and consider $\lambda = 0$, then the set $\{x \mid f(x) > \lambda\}$ is equal to $(0, \infty)$ and this is NOT one of the $2^4$ elements in our algebra. But you seem to be saying that it is in our algebra?

Comment: @AlgebraGuy You're welcome; I'm glad I could help. Regarding question 2, certainly $(0,\infty)$ is not in the algebra that we put on the domain of $f$.  The question is whether we put the same algebra on the codomain of $f$ (whereas you are assuming that we put the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the codomain of $f$.).  In general, if you have a function $f:X \to Y$ it makes no sense to ask whether $f$ is measurable unless you specify a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ and a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$.

Comment: ...We both seem to be assuming that, in the question at hand, the domain and co-domain are both $\mathbb{R}$ (although it doesn't make this explicit.) However, you seem to be assuming that on the domain we put the $\sigma$-algebra (call it $\mathcal{A}$) generated by the three intervals and on the codomain we put the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, whereas I am assuming that we put the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on both the domain and codomain.  The question is not clear on this point.

Comment: The domain is $\mathbb{R}$ with the $\mathcal{A}$ $\sigma$-algebra. The codomain is specified in the question as $\mathbb{R}$, I probably should mentioned that in my original post.

Comment: @AlgebraGuy Good. But we still haven't figured out what algebra to put on the co-domain.  You are implicitly assuming that it is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (_i.e._ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets $\{y \in \mathbb{R} : y > \lambda\}$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, or equivalently generated by the open sets.)  I just want to make sure that you understand you are making that assumption about the problem and that you believe it to be justified by the context.

Comment: Yes the algebra on the codomain isn't specified and we never dealt with algebras on the codomain in our course, I didn't even consider it until you mentioned it here!